# IoT streaming consumer architecture

Tags: http, apache-kafka

I have a set of IoT sensors in the field that generates 50,000 msgs/sec. I am able to successfully receive this data, transform it and store it in an outgoing Kafka topic. I have consumers that are interested in consuming these messages through a HTTP API. At this stage of execution, I am faced with an architectural decision, which I am hoping to get answered in this forum. Should this be a push or a pull stream? What are the pros and cons around each?. 
My data is pretty tiny and more or less doesn't change structure.

Also, does anyone know how to expose messages in Kafka through a streaming API?

Answer (score 1):

For exposing messages in Kafka in streaming way you can have a look at [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/). A good writeup on the use cases it caters to is [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/).
With this you can consume the messages in Kafka as a real time stream and push that to external services, database etc.

Regarding the architectural decision of using either pull or push that depends upon what would be the downstream consumers of this data and how would they like to consume it. As an e.g., the messages you are receiving in Kafka broker is transformed/aggregated etc. and then you have streaming consumers who write this to database which is exposed as a REST service ( via an application). Now your final consumers of this data can use this API for reporting/displaying purpose etc. If you have real time delivery requirements to end consumers you might use websockets etc rather than polling.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did look at Kafka Streams. Not sure if it actually provides a HTTP API (or HTTP2 ) for long lived connections. Also, my code is in Flink that processes the incoming messages and drops it to the consumer Kafka topic. I can't fit Kafka streams in this architecture anywhere. I was looking at Pushpin proxy (which is push), which is the only mechanism that provides me a rest API and hides all Kafka complexities from the consuming client.

Comment: Since you already are using Apache Flink , you don't need Kafka streams. By the way what kind of API are you envisioning for your clients. For REST API what input parameters would they pass? You may need to push these messages to another store and write an API over that. Or take a look at Kafka REST Proxy https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Comment: I do not want to write code using the Kafka Streams API. My stream data is already in Kafka. How do I make it available to the end clients in a streaming fashion using a standard HTTP Proxy/API? Using Kafka Streams will have me rewrite my code from Flink, which I do not want to do? Not sure if I am missing anything here or misunderstanding the stack.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Kafka REST Proxy

Comment: Or another option could be to write a Consumer for this data in Kafka, push it to some websocket server and let all your clients be a consumer of this websocket server recieving data in streaming fashion over http.

Comment: That's exactly what I was planning to do. In fact, Pushpin does that for you. It acts as a proxy between Kafka and your client and provides the client a simple REST API over HTTP or WebSockets. It hides all complexities of kafka consumer API the client shouldn't care about....However, the help in this space is limited. 
https://github.com/fanout/kafka-sse-example

Comment: Hmm..I'm getting it more now. Have you taken a look at https://hackernoon.com/supercharging-kafka-enable-realtime-web-streaming-by-adding-pushpin-fd62a9809d94

Comment: The consumer program here is written in Python so you might need to understand. Also here is something in java ( you might want to update to newer kafka version) https://github.com/b/kafka-websocket and this one contributed by Microsoft ( in NodeJS) https://github.com/microsoft/kafka-proxy-ws